# VPN not properly working after upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, vpn

I was using windscribe-cli also protonvpn-cli for vpn on Kubuntu18.04 and were working just fine.
Now, after a 20.04 clean install, windscribe 1.4-51 connects and reports an IP change but any browser times out. Windscribe depends on openvpn, resolvconf, stunnel4 all installed and presumably working.

Comment: Enable the VPN and post the output of `ip a`

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:1a:06:b0:b1:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.104/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0f0
       valid_lft 6570sec preferred_lft 6570sec

Comment: 3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:db:30:cc:af:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.104.1/24 brd 192.168.104.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.37.1/24 brd 172.16.37.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.121.70.14/23 brd 10.121.71.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: Installed opensuse tumbleweed on the same computer same result: can traceroute, can lookup my public ip in cli but all browsers timeout. Interesting enough, this happens only on wired eth; on wifi on my laptop, everything is fine; though, on desktop i have only eth and no plans to waste money on wlp. On win10 everything is just fine so it's not isp related

Comment: Does it work after running `ip link set dev vmnet8 mtu 1000`?

Comment: i traveled to a new location, still connected on eth
adrian@Aspire:~$ ip link set dev vmnet8 mtu 1000
Cannot find device "vmnet8"

Comment: Staff from windscribe instructed me to:
sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-resolved
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
which i did and it's working